# How to write an script to transform multiple RDL files into multiple XML files in python?

Tags: python, xml, transform, rdl

[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn9Te.png)[XML] I have "rdl.bat" which is used to transform RDL into XML in case of single file, I want to know about multiple files.

[here is the link of rdl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQkYK.png)ack.imgur.com/s6om4.png

Comment: Hello Parfait, Actually I have more than 2000 RDL files and I need to convert them all into there corresponding XML, I can't do this one by one, I am new to python. So, I want some help.

Comment: <root>
    <section name="some_map" define="true">
        <reg annon="true" name="reg1">
            <field annon="true" name="f1" offset="12:19">
                <EXPRESSION>
                    <EXPRESSION type="number">12</EXPRESSION>
                </EXPRESSION>
                <EXPRESSION>
                    <EXPRESSION type="number">19</EXPRESSION>
                </EXPRESSION>
                <EXPRESSION>
                    <EXPRESSION type="number">8'b10010110</EXPRESSION>
                </EXPRESSION>
            </field>       This is the XML.

Comment: Please have a look, post updated

Answer (score 0):

if you have rdl.bat you can create another bat file to call it for all .rdl files into folder:

```
for %%i in (C:\myrdlfiles\*.rdl) do rdl.bat %%i
```